# How do I create a 3-dimensional matrix in R?

Tags: r, arrays, matrix

According to this [site](https://www.bnlearn.com/examples/custom-fitted/), I should be able to create a 2 x 2 x 2 dimensional array/matrix as follows.

```
cptC = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.8)
dim(cptC) = c(2, 2, 2)
dimnames(cptC) = list("C" = c("TRUE", "FALSE"), "A" =  c("LOW", "HIGH"),"B" = c("GOOD", "BAD"))
```

However, when I print the `class(cptC)` I get `array`. When I print `typeof(cptC)` I get `double`. In Jupyter Lab, when I type in `cptC` I get the following output, which does not indicate a n-dimensional array.

```
0.50 .50 .40 .60 .30 .70 .20 .8
```

Although `dim(cptC)` gives me `2 2 2`.

What I am expecting to see in Jupyter Lab is the following.

```
> cptC
, , B = GOOD

       A
C       LOW HIGH
  TRUE  0.5  0.4
  FALSE 0.5  0.6

, , B = BAD

       A
C       LOW HIGH
  TRUE  0.3  0.2
  FALSE 0.7  0.8
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

I am on R v4.2.1 on Mac Ventura 13.5.2 (M1 Pro CPU).

Comment: A _matrix_ is a by definition two-dimensional but you are well on your way discovering that _arrays_ can in fact have N dimensions (though they become harder to print "in two dimensions").

Comment: seems like this is a question for jupyter lab not r

Comment: @rawr You are right in the sense that the code is "correct" but the output is misleading, so this question would be better for Jupyter Lab. When I put the code in the R REPL, the output is as expected. I think Dirk was also helpful in hinting that n-dimensional (n >= 3) arrays are difficult to print in 2 dimensions (might explain why Jupyter Lab prints what it does). The useful thing about this post could just be "print in the R REPL" to reinforce confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is created correctly. To get the same output in Jupyter Lab as in R use:

```
print(cptC)
```